# Angular directive : child template with parent var

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, directive

I try to figure out how directives work in angular. I want to sort a table but I have an issue with child directive. I don't know how to use vars used in parent directive.
(code is written in coffeescript)

view HTML

```
<table extend-table table-params="tableParams">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th field="number">Number</th>
         <th field="name">Name</th>
       </tr>
</table>
```

Controller : field is the sorted field

```
$scope.tableParams =
  field: "name"
  sorting: "asc"
```

Parent directive : I parse all th, select th with field attr and add the child directive to it

```
class ExtendTable
  constructor: ($compile) ->

     link = (scope, element, attrs) ->
        angular.forEach element.find('th'), (th) ->
           th = angular.element(th)

           if th.attr("field")
              field = th.attr("field")

              th.append $compile('<sort-column></sort-column>') scope

              th.bind 'click', () ->
                 if scope.tableParams.field != field
                     scope.tableParams.field   = field
                     scope.tableParams.sorting = 'asc'
                 else
                     if scope.tableParams.sorting == 'asc'
                         scope.tableParams.sorting = 'desc'
                     else
                         scope.tableParams.sorting = 'asc'

     return {
       restrict: 'A'
       scope: true
       link
     }
@myApp.directive 'extendTable', ['$compile', ExtendTable]
```

Child directive : tableParams.field is the sorted column and field is the clicked column

```
class SortColumn

  constructor: () ->
    return {
      restrict: 'E'
      scope:true
      require: '^extendTable'
      template: '<div class="pull-right">
                   <i ng-class="{
                         \'fa\':true, 
                         \'fa-sort\':scope.tableParams.field!=field, 
                         \'fa-sort-asc sort-active\':scope.tableParams.field==field&&scope.tableParams.sorting==\'asc\', 
                         \'fa-sort-desc sort-active\':scope.tableParams.field==field&&scope.tableParams.sorting==\'desc\'}"
                   ></i>
                 </div>'
    }
@myApp.directive 'sortColumn', [SortColumn]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

either dont make an isolated scope (`scope:true` -> `scope:false`) then you can access in ng-class by `tableParams` (you dont have to use scope.). If scope is false then its refering to the parent scope. 
If you leave `scope: true`, you can use `$parent.tableParams` to access the parent scope variable. 
You are using `field` in the ng-class which is not assign to any scope. It is a local variable in the iteration, which is not accessable here. You have to assign it to the scope or to the child scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed my approach, now it works fine. I just need time to understand angular's directive correctly.

Comment: Was my answer useful to you? Just asking, because you did not voted up . Also would be nice to share your solution, if mine was not ok, to others could know it, if they found this page.